# Do YouTube views on a smart tv or TiVo get logged as a specific type of referral?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, referrals, tivo

I want to see all my views that are from a Smart TV or a TiVo. Does anyone know if they have a specific referral code logged in with their view? For example, I can see how many people have watched my video on a mobile device because it says "First view from a mobile device" then the number of views. Is there something like this for Smart TV's or TiVo's views?

Thanks,
Tyler